# Mongoose delete array item in every subdocument

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have an [User (click)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SEdme.png) Model with a cart where products are stored (just the id).
If I want to delete a product from the Shop, the product should be also deleted from every users cart.

Therefore I tried this code:

```
User.update({ $pull: {'cart.items': {productId: product._id }}});
```

Even if I want to delete the product from a specific User with findByIdAndUpdate, it doesn't work:

```
User.findByIdAndUpdate(user._id, { $pull: {'cart.items': {productId: product._id }}});
```

Answer (score 0):

just try:

```
User.update({},{ $pull: {'cart.items': {productId: product._id }}});
```

Comment: Hi, thats not possible, cart.items is an array, see the photo on "User"

Comment: you right, I've updated my answer, check it

Comment: Already tried that. I also tried .updateMany() :/

Comment: no you are missing `{}` at the first argument, check it

Comment: I'm not, i tried {}: `User.updateMany({},{ $pull: {'cart.items': {productId: product._id }}})` (same with .update())